# Which software installer should I use with Alpine?

Tags: package-management, docker, alpine-linux

I am experimenting with the Python Docker container, which seems to use Alpine Linux.  I'm not familiar with Alpine and I don't see it listed as an option for installing software.

On Alpine, should I follow software installation instructions for RedHat, Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, or SUSE?

Comment: Have you tried googling? First result for "alpine software installer / package installer / package manager": https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/apk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am experimenting with the Python Docker container, which seems to use Alpine Linux.

No, only the `python:alpine` container is based on Alpine, `python`, `python:slim` are based on debian.

> On Alpine, should I follow software installation instructions for RedHat, Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, or SUSE?

None of these.

You need to know how to install software on Alpine. That's different than all of the above.

If you're not familiar with Alpine, the container you chose might simply be the wrong one for you. Instead of `python:alpine` simply use `python`, `python:slim`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what software you're talking about.  If it's software managed by `pip`, then this would likely work the same way on Alpine Linux as on any other system with `pip` installed, and assuming you are using the `python:alpine` container, *`pip` itself is already installed*.

When installing other (non-Python) packages, like `curl` or whatnot, the Alpine Linux system uses its own distinctive package manager called `apk` (the Alpine Package Keeper).  It works slightly differently from `yum` or `apt` and the other package managers, but it's fairly intuitive for basic usage.  This site is not the place for giving tutorials, so I suggest that you instead [read up on it](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/apk.html) on your own. The only thing you may want to be aware of is that packages may be named slightly differently between systems using different package management tools and that the availability of packages or specific versions of packages may vary.

```bash
$ docker run --rm --tty --interactive python:alpine /bin/sh
/ # apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.18.3-108-g8b22d1676dc [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main]
v3.18.3-110-g94f9602df3e [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community]
OK: 20064 distinct packages available
/ # apk add curl
(1/6) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r14)
(2/6) Installing libunistring (1.1-r1)
(3/6) Installing libidn2 (2.3.4-r1)
(4/6) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.55.1-r0)
(5/6) Installing libcurl (8.2.1-r0)
(6/6) Installing curl (8.2.1-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r2.trigger
OK: 19 MiB in 44 packages
/ # curl --version
curl 8.2.1 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/8.2.1 OpenSSL/3.1.2 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.4 nghttp2/1.55.1
Release-Date: 2023-07-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp ws wss
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```